# Python lxml XPATH -- find an attribute of all parents of particular node

Tags: python, xpath, svg, lxml

In an SVG file, I use `xpath` to find a node that contains a relative SVG path, for example,

```
<path d="m -0.3,-0.3 l 0.6,0 l 0,0.6 l -0.6,0 l 0,-0.6 z" transform="translate(-1 -0.5)"/>
```

Various parents of this node all the way to the root will have a

```
transform="translate(X Y)"
```

attribute that determines the actual placement location of the relative path above. What is the right/concise/efficient way to capture the parents of this path/node all the way to the root, particularly those that have the 'transform' attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the right/concise/efficient way to capture the parents of this
>   path/node all the way to the root, particularly those that have the
>   'transform' attribute?

**Use**:

```
ancestor::*[@transform]
```

This selects all ancestor elements that have a `transform` attribute.

**One can select directly all `transform` attributes of the ancestors**:

```
ancestor::*/@transform
```

**If you are interested only in those `transform` attributes, whose string value starts with the string "translate("** (possibly preceded by white space), use:

```
ancestor::*/@transform[starts-with(normalize-space(@transform),'translate(')]
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! One thing: `@transform` works when selecting ancestor *elements*, but when directly selecting transform attributes starting w/ “translate(”, it should be `.` instead — `ancestor::*/@transform[starts-with(normalize-space(.),'translate(')]`

Comment: @HonoreDoktorr, Yes, the answer is for the specific question and for a multitude of out-of scope other possible questions. For example, another variation, when needing the attributes of both the ancestors and the context item itself, one can use the `ancestor-or-self::` axis

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
'ancestor::*[starts-with(@transform,"translate")]'
```

For example:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

content = '''
<bar transform="translate(1 1)">
<foo transform="translate(1 1)">
<path d="m -0.3,-0.3 l 0.6,0 l 0,0.6 l -0.6,0 l 0,-0.6 z" transform="translate(-1 -0.5)"/>
</foo>
</bar>
'''
doc = ET.fromstring(content)
for path in doc.xpath('//path'):
    print(path.xpath('ancestor::*[starts-with(@transform,"translate")]'))
```

yields

```
[<Element bar at 0xb749448c>, <Element foo at 0xb7494504>]
```

Comment: While this answer got me through the problem, and was first, @Dimitre's answer is more explanatory, so I chose it as the solution. Thanks!